# Want to convert String to Byte in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, byte, arrays

How can we convert string to byte array in iPhone?

Please help I am new to iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it in `NSData` then use:

```
NSData* bytes = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

If you want a char array then use:

```
[str getCString:chrBuff maxLength:[str length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```